# Dismissing DialogFragment with FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am displaying a DialogFragment and `onClickOK` event the AsyncTask is started. While AsyncTask is running I am showing ProgressBar. AsyncTask can finish with fail or fail. When it finish with success I would like to dismiss FragmentDialog. How can I do it with `FragmentManager`(?) ? I show it using `void show (FragmentManager manager,  String tag)`.

P.S. Is there any reason to dismiss a FragmentDialog `onClickOK` and (perhaps) show it on finish AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AsyncTask you can dismiss dialog reference on postexecuted method and launch it onPreExcetuded

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialogo = ProgressDialog.show.....


@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
        if (dialogo != null && dialogo.isShowing())
            dialogo.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by using the same tag used to show it and then dismiss it.

```
Fragment fragment = yourFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dialog_tag");
if (fragment != null) {
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) fragment;
    dialogFragment.dismiss();
}
```